# F# Printing out a 2D String Array

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#, printf

I'm currently working on a board game called Neutron.

```
let boardArray = array2D [ ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "1"; "*"; "2"; "*"; "3"; "*"; "4"; "*"; "5"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "N"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"; "0"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "A"; "*"; "B"; "*"; "C"; "*"; "D"; "*"; "E"; "*"];
                           ["*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"; "*"] ]
```

I have this string array. My question is, how do I go about printing an array like this?

My initial thought was to use a nested for loop to print out some `boardArray.[row, column]`, but, from what I understand, the `row` item in

`for row in boardArray do` is of type obj; and I can't exactly pass through an obj where an int is needed. Is there a conversion I can work with? A different approach that I should be using? Am I severely misunderstanding the usage of F# for each loops?

Comment: Your first problem is that the variable you've (mis-) named `row` is not going to hold rows but individual elements.  The for-do loop will iterate 121 times in your example, not 11.  You're not misunderstanding the `for` loop, but rather the behavior of a two-dimensional .NET array.  You could iterate by casting to `string` or by using `Array2D.iter` (for example `boardArray |> Array2D.iter (printfn "%s")`).

Answer (score 4):

Solved by using for..to loop as such:

```
let initiateBoard = 
 for r = 0 to Array2D.length1 boardArray - 1 do
  for c = 0 to Array2D.length2 boardArray - 1 do
   printfn "%A " boardArray.[r, c]
```

This will print out each element on a new line, so a separate function for handling spacing is needed beyond this.

Comment: Where did you get length1 and 2 from?

Answer (score 4):

Is each item in the board always going to be a single character? If so, then I'd recommend changing your data type a little bit.

First, if each item in the board will always be a single character, then it makes more sense to use `char`s, not strings, as the data type for each board position, like so:

```
let boardArray = array2D [ ['*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'; '*'];
                           ['*'; '1'; '*'; '2'; '*'; '3'; '*'; '4'; '*'; '5'; '*'];
                           // Etc.
                         ]
```

But there's an even better way to represent a 2D array of characters like this, and that's as a 1-dimensional array of *strings*, where each string is a row:

```
let boardArray = [| "***********";
                    "*1*2*3*4*5*"
                    // Etc.
                 |]
```

Now to access the character at row `r` and column `c`, instead of writing `board.[r, c]` you'd write `board.[r].[c]`. If that bothers you, you can write a helper function like so:

```
let getChar (row, col) board = board.[row].[col]
```

and then use it like so:

```
board |> getChar (1, 3)
```

This is the equivalent of doing `board.[1, 3]` in the `array2d` representation you're currently using.

Then printing the board becomes very easy:

```
for row in board do
    printfn "%s" row
```

Changing an item in the board is slightly harder since strings are immutable, but you can define a helper function for "make a new string with the contents of the old string except for this replacement character at this index":

```
let replaceAt idx (ch : char) (s : string) =
    let len = s.Length
    let before = s.Substring(0, idx)
    let after = if idx >= len then "" else s.Substring(idx+1, len-idx-1)
    sprintf "%s%c%s" before ch after
```

Usage:

```
"*1*2*3*4*5*" |> replaceAt 1 'X'  // Returns "*X*2*3*4*5*"
```

So to replace the item at row 1, col 3 with 'X', you could do:

```
board.[1] <- board.[1] |> replaceAt 3 'X'
```

Or if you're choosing *not* to mutate your arrays, and instead creating a new array for each board state, then you'd do so with the following helper functions:

```
let replaceItemInArray idx (newItem : 'T) (arr : 'T []) =
    arr |> Array.mapi (fun i oldItem -> if i = idx then newItem else oldItem)

let updateBoard newItem (row, col) oldBoard =
    let oldRowContents = oldBoard.[row]
    let newRowContents = oldRowContents |> replaceAt col newItem
    oldBoard |> replaceItemInArray row newRowContents
```

If you're curious about the `Array.mapi` function that I used, [its documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.mapi%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d).

Answer (score 0):

F# has a slice syntax that can handle this:

```
let boardArray = Array2D.zeroCreate 5 5

for y in 0 .. boardArray.GetLength(1) - 1 do
    printfn "%A" boardArray.[*,y]
```